# Need to access Mac via ssh remotely through another Mac with Internet Sharing

Tags: macos, ssh, sftp, airport

My setup at office is:

Internet -> AirportExtreme --(wifi)--> AirportExpress --(eth)--> MacPro1 --(eth)--> MacPro2

I want to be able to access MacPro2 from laptop at home via ssh (and sftp).

Is it possible?

1. The AirportExtreme is set to "DHCP and NAT" and is doling out 10.0.1.xxx IPs.
2. The AirportExpress is 10.0.1.2.
3. MacPro1 is 10.0.1.3 via Ethernet to AirportExpress.
4. It is then connected by 2nd Ethernet port (192.168.2.1) to MacPro2, which is 192.168.2.2.

Is there any way to "tunnel through" to MacPro2 from home?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you managed to connect to MacPro1 yet?

Comment: I've found a "workaround" for now ... LogMeIn Hamachi!

Comment: You're going to have to find a way to ssh to MacPro1 first.